# Get relative path in Django

Tags: javascript, django, django-models, django-templates

I've created a map where I want to implement some kml files into it . If i harcode the url it works but im trying to pass it through a variable because Im dealing with many kml files in a for loop.
Even though the url path im getting in console is right i dont get the result i need.Any idea how to fix that?

**view:**

```
def map(request):
    field_list = models.Field.objects.all()
    context = {
        "title": "Map",
        "field_list": field_list,
    }
    template = 'agriculture/map.html'
    return render(request, template, context)
```

If i hardcode the url it goes like this :

```
var polygon = omnivore.kml("{% static '../media/kml/user_admin/2022-04-07-2-Arnissa_cherry.kml' %}", ... );
```

I've tried doing it like this but even though the path Im getting is correct it seems django does not read the path(kml is the FileField in my model):

**map.html**

```
{% for field in field_list %}
    $(".search_area").append(new Option("{{field.friendly_name}}")); //friendly name 
   
var kmldir = "../media/" + "{{field.kml.name}}"
console.log(kmldir) // ../media/kml/user_admin/2022-04-07-2-Arnissa_cherry.kml

var polygon = omnivore.kml("{% static 'kmldir' %}", null, new L.GeoJSON(null, { //file url
    style: function() {
        return {
            color: 'red',
            transparent: true,
            opacity: 1,
            fillOpacity: 0.05
        }}     
}));  
kml_arr.push([polygon, "{% static 'kmldir' %}"]); //file url
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: If you've set your **MEDIA_URL** then you can access it like this ***`{{field.kml.url}}`*** this will give serve you your file from url.

Comment: MEDIA_URL is correct it points to media so I used it like :  `("{% static '../{{field.kml.url}' %}"` but still get no result even though path is correct

Comment: Check this **`var kmldir = "{{field.kml.url}}"`**

Comment: Unfortunately no thats the way I tried assigning a variable doesnt change anything though.

Comment: Maybe Im using the path wrong i used `var kmldir` and then `var polygon = omnivore.kml("{% static 'kmldir' %}"` maybe that is wrong ?

Comment: I've also tried with 
```var kmldir = "{% get_media_prefix %} + "{{field.kml.name}}"
var polygon = omnivore.kml("{% static 'kmldir' %}" ``` which points to the same url but with no result

Comment: Hello @haduki provide your `Field` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried a different approach and it worked

```
{% for field in field_list %}

    {% with "../media/"|add:field.kml.name as fieldname %}       

        $(".search_area").append(new Option("{{ field.friendly_name }}")); //friendly name 

         var polygon = omnivore.kml('{% static fieldname %}', null, new L.GeoJSON(null, { //file url
            style: function() {
                return {
                    color: 'red',
                    transparent: true,
                    opacity: 1,
                    fillOpacity: 0.05
                }
            }
        }));

             kml_arr.push([polygon, '{% static fieldname %}']); //file url
    {% endwith %}

{% endfor %}
```